# Laravel validation is case sensitive in ends_with

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

It looks small problem but I can't find the best solution.
In Laravel validation, I need to check if the user enters the company email and I'm using `ends_with` check. But it is case sensitive

```
$request->validate([
    'username' => [...],
    'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:50', 'unique:users', 'ends_with:mycompany.com'],     
      ]);
```

So if the user enters `mycompany.com` it will pass the validation but fails when entering `MYCOMPANY.COM` or `MYCompany.com`

Comment: before calling the validate fn do: ``$request->email = strtolower($request->email);`` or ``$request->email = Str::lower($request->email);``

Comment: I'd maybe create my own rule, and there i'd check it manually `$result = Str::endsWith(Str::lower('LARAVEL'), Str::lower('vEL')); // true`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `PrepareForValidation` method in form request.
First make the form request by : `PHP artisan make request`, then add this method to class :

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
  {
     $this->merge([
            'email' => strtolower($this->email),
        ]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create a separate request, using `artisan make:request`, you can format the data before it goes through the validation with the `prepareForValidation` method

You can read more on that here
https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#form-request-validation